# execute a java program through batch script

Tags: java, jar, batch-file

I have a java class "Test.java" which contains certain code.

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    testMount();
}

public static void testMount() throws Exception {
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("os.name"));
    //Windows
    String volumeToMount = "\\\\?\\Volume{****-****-******-********}\\";
    String mountPoint = "C:\\temp\\";

    mountFileSystem("", "", volumeToMount, mountPoint); //This carries out the operation        
}
}
```

I have already compiled the code in Linux Operating System. I want to run the compiled code through a batch script ( .bat file). How do i do that? What is the syntax for that? If i have to add some external jars, where and how do I insert them in the syntax within the .bat file?

Comment: you should include the external jars in compilation (you should have an option to compile external libraries in eclipse/netbeans) when you are exporting the project into jar

Comment: You say that you compiled it under Linux but .bat files are Windows batch files. Do you want hints for Windows or Linux?

Comment: I've compiled them in Linux.But i want to run those compiled files in windows.

Answer (score 3):

here is an example of bat file for executing a java code from the jar with external jars:

```
@echo off

if "X%JAVA_HOME%" == "X" goto setjavahome
goto setup

:setjavahome
rem #### MODIFY ##########
set JAVA_HOME=c:\program files\javasoft\jre\1.2
rem #######################

:setup
set JNDI_LIB=lib\ldap.jar;lib\jndi.jar;lib\providerutil.jar;lib\ldapbp.jar
set JSSE_LIB=lib\jsse.jar;lib\jnet.jar;lib\jcert.jar

set COMMON=.;%JNDI_LIB%;%JSSE_LIB%
set EXEC=browser.jar lbe.ui.BrowserApp

set CMD="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -cp %COMMON%;%EXEC%

echo %CMD%
%CMD%
```

Answer (score 0):

.bat is for Windows; try to compile your Java codes in Windows to EXE (with your external libraries, as suggested by galchen), and add your EXE name along with relative / absolute path to the batch file.

For example, the output EXE is named as test.exe, the batch file should contain:

```
START C:\PATH\TO\YOUR\EXE\test.exe
```

Advantage of compiling to EXE is mainly for performance.